# How to install Cypress for CI/CD pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline, cypress, e2e-testing

I need to use Cypress in my Jenkins pipeline. Since downloading the cypress binaries takes way many minutes, I decided to create a docker image with cypress installed globally.

I got a message saying that globally cypress installation is a bad practice, and I should install cypress as a depDependency. Since every time the pipeline runs, it pulls the source code and installs the dependencies, I can't afford to spend all that time just to run the tests.

I wonder if someone has an alternative or advice to have the best practice without downloading the huge binaries of cypress every time my pipeline runs

Answer (score 0):

Here's the repo with examples of running Cypress on various CI platforms, including Jenkins: [cypress-example-kitchensink](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-kitchensink).